# passing parameter in Mysql Stored proc within unix script

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, unix, unix-timestamp, amazon-aurora

I need to pass a parameter in mysql stored proc(RDS aurora). I am calling stored proc from unix script. somehow its not working. Please suggest where it went wrong?
below unix script. This is calling the stored proc but not passing parameter.
echo $DATE is showing '2021-09-25' which is expected value to pass.

```
     echo $DATE
 $MYSQL_CMD -e " use $MY_DATABASE; call $PROC_NAME($DATE); show warnings;"
```

--

```
 DELIMITER $$

USE `mydb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `my_proc`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `my_proc`(IN update_date VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN

DECLARE var_update_date VARCHAR(10);

SELECT NOW() AS 'start Time';

SELECT update_date;
--
end
```

output from mysql stored proc

```
start Time
2021-10-28 09:29:59
update_date
1987
```

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around `$DATE`.

```
$MYSQL_CMD -e " use $MY_DATABASE; call $PROC_NAME('$DATE'); show warnings;"
```

Comment: Thanks man, This works great.